# Convert text file into json format or filter out key and value pair

Tags: python, json, regex

I try to perform a task that can find out the key and value from a txt file. 
There are some ideas in my mind. 1.using regex 2.turning txt to json.

I'm having difficulties to filter and convert the format. Is there any good ways to do this or any available api can perform such tasks?

txt file:

```
System:    Host: ict-vm Kernel: 4.4.0-53-generic i686 (32 bit)
           Desktop: MATE 1.16.1  Distro: Linux Mint 18.1 Serena
Machine:   System: ASUSTeK (portable) product: N43SN v: 1.0
           Mobo: ASUSTeK model: N43SN v: 1.0 serial: NB-1234567890
           Bios: American Megatrends v: N43SN.412 date: 09/21/2011
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i7-2670QM (-HT-MCP-) cache: 6144 KB 
           clock speeds: max: 3100 MHz 1: 807 MHz 2: 814 MHz 3: 800 MHz
           4: 1078 MHz 5: 990 MHz 6: 811 MHz 7: 801 MHz 8: 844 MHz
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
           Card-2: NVIDIA GF108M [GeForce GT 550M]
           Display Server: X.org 1.18.4 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) FAILED: nouveau
           tty size: 80x24 Advanced Data: N/A for root
Audio:     Card Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Family High Definition Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.4.0-53-generic
Network:   Card-1: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
           driver: ath9k
           IF: wlp3s0 state: up mac: 7x:2t:61:d4:72:8a
           Card-2: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet driver: atl1c
           IF: enp4s0 state: down mac: 14:da:e1:ay:72:b5
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 507.9GB (0.4% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: ST95005620AS size: 500.1GB
           ID-2: USB /dev/sdb model: DataTraveler_3.0 size: 7.8GB
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 48.0C mobo: N/A gpu: 43.0
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 223 Uptime: 40 min Memory: 531.1/3948.3MB
           Client: Shell (sudo) inxi: 2.2.35System:    Host: ict-vm Kernel: 4.4.0-53-generic i686 (32 bit)
           Desktop: MATE 1.16.1  Distro: Linux Mint 18.1 Serena
Machine:   System: ASUSTeK (portable) product: N43SN v: 1.0
           Mobo: ASUSTeK model: N43SN v: 1.0 serial: NB-1234567890
           Bios: American Megatrends v: N43SN.412 date: 09/21/2011
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i7-2670QM (-HT-MCP-) cache: 6144 KB 
           clock speeds: max: 3100 MHz 1: 807 MHz 2: 814 MHz 3: 800 MHz
           4: 1078 MHz 5: 990 MHz 6: 811 MHz 7: 801 MHz 8: 844 MHz
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
           Card-2: NVIDIA GF108M [GeForce GT 550M]
           Display Server: X.org 1.18.4 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) FAILED: nouveau
           tty size: 80x24 Advanced Data: N/A for root
Audio:     Card Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Family High Definition Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.4.0-53-generic
Network:   Card-1: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
           driver: ath9k
           IF: wlp3s0 state: up mac: 7x:2t:61:d4:72:8a
           Card-2: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet driver: atl1c
           IF: enp4s0 state: down mac: 14:da:e1:ay:72:b5
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 507.9GB (0.4% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: ST95005620AS size: 500.1GB
           ID-2: USB /dev/sdb model: DataTraveler_3.0 size: 7.8GB
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 48.0C mobo: N/A gpu: 43.0
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 223 Uptime: 40 min Memory: 531.1/3948.3MB
           Client: Shell (sudo) inxi: 2.2.35
```

json file:

```
{
   System: {
      Host:'ict-vm',
      Kernel:'4.4.0-53-generic i686 (32 bit)',
       .....
      },
   Machine:{
      System: 'ASUSTeK (portable)'
    }
}
```

Expected result: I can get values using keys

```
print(node['System'])
```

Output:

```
ASUSTeK (portable)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that really the format of the file, or did StackOverflow eat some newlines?

Comment: @Bemmu I just updated the txt format. That's the file I'm trying to convert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file format is fixed and there are no nested dicts then this can be easily turned to dict using

```
import re
x="""System:       Host: ict-vm Kernel: 4.4.0-53-generic i686 (32 bit) Desktop: MATE 1.16.1  Distro: Linux Mint 18.1 Serena
Machine:      System: ASUSTeK (portable) product: N43SN v: 1.0 Mobo: ASUSTeK model: N43SN v: 1.0 serial: NB-1234567890 Bios: American Megatrends v: N43SN.412 date: 09/21/2011"""
y = re.findall(r"(\S+):\s*(.*?)(?=\s*\S+:|$)",x)
d={}
for i,j in y:
    if not j:
        d[i]={}
        k=d[i]
    else:
        k[i]=j
print d
```

Output:

`{'Machine': {'product': 'N43SN', 'Mobo': 'ASUSTeK', 'System': 'ASUSTeK (portable)', 'Bios': 'American Megatrends', 'v': 'N43SN.412', 'date': '09/21/2011', 'model': 'N43SN', 'serial': 'NB-1234567890'}, 'System': {'Kernel': '4.4.0-53-generic i686 (32 bit)', 'Host': 'ict-vm', 'Distro': 'Linux Mint 18.1 Serena', 'Desktop': 'MATE 1.16.1'}}`

You can access using `d['Machine']['System']`

Output: `ASUSTeK (portable)`

EDIT:

For the new input file we would need to tweak the regex.So use

```
\s*([^:\n]+):\s*((?:(?!: |\n)[\s\S])*)(?=\s+[^:\n]+:|$)
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/EcIcPJ/1

Comment: it's pretty much what I need but it comes out different output than yours. I just updated my txt file format above.

Comment: Thank you so much. That's exactly what I want.